# HTML/CSS : Is it a bad practice to separate the text content from the background layers?

Tags: html, layout, background, css-position, absolute

I have a simple page integration to make.
The page is approximately 7 pages(viewport) height for a desktop view.
I have multiple text content.
But I also have different backgrounds, which are blocks of colors essentially but not horizontally, so I have to play with the rotate property.. not a big deal.

- The main question is if for positioning the backgrounds, I would use absolute/relative positioning.
- But then my text content would be affected.
- Is it interesting to duplicate my main layout, in order to have from one side only background div's, on the other only text content. So the main text would exactly match the main background but would be displayed at the top of it...?
- example:
  Instead of having :

```html
    <main>
       <section>
           <div class="some background"></div>
           <article> h2 ... p... </article>
       </section>
    </main>
```

having this:

```html
    <main class="backgrounds">
        <section>
           <div class="some background"></div>
       </section>
    </main>
    <main class="text">
        <section>
           <article> h2 ... p... </article>
       </section>
    </main>
```

Where main is absolute and .text is z-index: 10, for example.
Of course, this is a very simplified example.
Is it a good or bad practice?

Thank you all in advance.

Max.

Comment: Using `main` and/or `section` for only a background (i.e. having no useful content) is certainly bad practice... Anyway: Why don't you use background images in CSS for your sections, main or body?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer.
yes of course you are right, I wasn't paying attention to the semantics...
I wanted to see if i could do it with pure CSS... Also to have more control over the responsive